# Unable to link div tag using <a>

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to link my div tag by wrapping `<a href="link"></a>` around it but it isn't working and removing the div container entirely.

This is what my website is supposed to look like:
[image]

But once I add the `<a>` tags it becomes like this and disappears:
[image]

Here is my react code:

```
const SdgBackground = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex-container">
            <a href="https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/poverty/"><div className="sdg1"></div></a>
            <div className="sdg2"></div>
            <div className="sdg3"></div>
            <div className="sdg4"></div>
            <div className="sdg5"></div>
            <div className="sdg6"></div>
            <div className="sdg7"></div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default SdgBackground
```

Here is my styling:

```
/* SDG boxes section */
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-color: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(244,247,252,0.5) 0%,rgba(244,247,252,0.5) 100%);
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.flex-container > div {
    background-color: white;
    width: 18vh;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18vh;
    font-size: 30px;
}

/* All SDG icons */
.sdg1 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg1.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg1:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(60%);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.sdg2 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg2.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg3 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg3.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg4 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg4.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg5 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg5.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg6 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg6.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}

.sdg7 {
    background: url("../assets/SDGIcons/sdg7.png"); 
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Only the div with the `<a>` wrapped around it is not showing, otherwise the rest are showing on the screen.

I'm using vanilla react and I still see the div when I do view source.

Comment: Need more context. do you have any styling? are you using Next.js or just vanilla react? do you see the div if you view source?

Comment: Why didn't you write anything inside `.sdg1` ? empty tags are removed by default by the react virtual DOM.

Comment: @denodster I made edits to my post, hopefully that's enough context

Comment: @Sobhani it's because I need it to be empty since I'm having it as a background image to cover the div

Comment: Remember that if you have an HMTL+CSS problem, don't just post code, post a runnable snippet. Having said that, is there any reason you're using `<div>` instead of `<span>` with `display: inline-block" so you can set width _and_ height?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not sure how to do that, is there any docs on stackoverflow that teaches us how to do that?

Comment: @Soccerball123 consider putting your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: @Soccerball123 hit edit, and then click the "snippet" button in the editor button bar. It's next to the image button.

Comment: @Spectric we have runnable snippets for a reason, third party links are explicitly discouraged in the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) unless it's not an html/css/js question (in which case runnable snippets obviously won't work, and then you're asked to only post links _in addition_ to having at least mcve code in your post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a non-breaking space in your empty divs.

```
const SdgBackground = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex-container">
            <a href="https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/poverty/"><div className="sdg1">&nbsp;</div></a>
            <div className="sdg2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="sdg3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="sdg4">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="sdg5">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="sdg6">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="sdg7">&nbsp;</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>
            <div>SDG</div>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default SdgBackground
```

Also you may want to consider a different approach in general as your site will not be accessable at all, and will probably have SEO issues. you've got all the no-no's: Text in images, images as backgrounds instead of explicit  with alt text, etc.

Try something like this:

```
<a href="https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/poverty/"><img alt="No Poverty" src="sdg1.png" /></a>
```

or better yet re-cut your images and put the text in the markup:

```
<a href="https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/poverty/"><img alt="Icon of a family in Poverty" src="poorfamily.png" />No Poverty</a>
```

then style the background with just a color using css and position the text and image accordingly. This is probably more work, so the other option is probably the best compromise.

Comment: How can I fix this? I'm not sure what you mean by not accessable at all. Could I just have some guidance as to what I could do better sorry I'm new to web dev

Comment: Try using a screen reader to access your website, you'll find that your menu is basically invisible to the screen reader. This means that the blind will not be able to use your website, now this might not be an issue because your market might not include the blind. But consider that webcrawlers are very similar as they don't necessarlially have a way to OCR your images, especially when they are background images. so google might not rank you very high. I'll add some above to nudge you in the right direction.